# How to configure a Jenkins plugin from a Dockerfile

Tags: github, jenkins, plugins, configuration, dockerfile

I have a user that just has access to pull from github.  In my Dockerfile I have added the plugins for Jenkins, such as github:1.22.4, but I want to configure the plugins as some of the people that will build the image won't know how to do the configuration, and don't care to learn.

So, I have some plugins for Jenkins and I want to be able to configure them using the Dockerfile.  How can I do that?

My Dockerfile is pretty basic right now:

```
FROM jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /plugins.txt
```

and I have several plugins in plugins.txt, but the one I want to configure is to pull the code from github.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this git repository?](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)

lets say you have `plugins.txt` like:

```
github:1.22.4
maven-plugin:2.7.1
ant:1.3
```

and `Dockerfile` like in your question.

You can take a look into [`example of plugins.sh`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/plugins.sh) and here is part for installing plugins. since you want do configure some plugins you can add configuration when you are installing plugin:

> ```
> if ! grep -q "${plugin[0]}:${plugin[1]}" "$TEMP_ALREADY_INSTALLED"
> then
>     echo "Downloading ${plugin[0]}:${plugin[1]}"
>
>     curl --retry 3 --retry-delay 5 -sSL -f "${JENKINS_UC_DOWNLOAD}/plugins/${plugin[0]}/${plugin[1]}/${plugin[0]}.hpi" -o "$REF/${plugin[0]}.jpi"
>     unzip -qqt "$REF/${plugin[0]}.jpi"
>
>     # if [ some plugin ] then
>     # here your configuration
>     # fi
>
>     (( COUNT_PLUGINS_INSTALLED += 1 ))
> else
>     echo "  ... skipping already installed:  ${plugin[0]}:${plugin[1]}"
> fi
> ```